# CSS Sprite Button, how to fix the postion during scaling

Tags: css, button, responsive-design

I am working on trying to convert this single webpage http://brandyderr.com/ to one that is responsive.

But I can't figure out how to keep each button in place as the site scales for devices.

Any ideas or tutorials would be great.

Thanks,

John

Comment: First, you need the viewport meta tag in the head. And you could create a wrapper with position: relative and add media queries to certain widths of screen

Comment: Please narrow down the issue and post any relevant code in the question itself. Don't link to a page which could very well be changed or revamped later on.